# Epimorphism in simplex category is split

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, epimorphisms

Consider $\Delta$ the simplex category, with objects $[n]=\{0,\dots,n\}$ and morphisms $f:[n]\to [m]$ such that $i<j\implies f(i)\leq f(j)$ (my definition is with $i<j$). I have shown that epimorphisms are exactly surjective maps.

Now I want to show that epimorphisms are split, that is if $f:[n]\to [m]$ is surjective, then $\exists s:[m]\to [n]$ such that $f\circ s=id_{[m]}$. To do so I'm told to use cosimplicial identities, that is $\delta^j \delta^i=\delta^i \delta^{j-1}$ and $\sigma^j \sigma^i=\sigma^i \sigma^{j+1}$ which are defined for $n\geq 1$ and $0\leq j \leq n$ by:

$\delta^j:[n-1]\to[n]$, $\delta^j(x)=x$ if $x<j$, $\delta^j(x)=x+1$ if $x\geq j$

$\sigma^j:[n+1]\to[n]$, $\sigma^j(x)=x$ if $x\leq j$, $\sigma^j(x)=x-1$ if $x>j$

However ignoring this and defining $s:[m]\to [n]$ by $s(x)=\text{min}\{y\in[n]|f(y)=x\}$ (exists since $f$ surjective) we get a section of $f$ (at least I think).

We have that $f(s(x))=f(\text{min}\{y\in[n]|f(y)=x\})=x$
If $x<y$, suppose for contradiction that $s(x)>s(y)$, then $f(s(y))\leq f(s(x))\implies y\leq x$ absurd so $f$ is split.

I have two questions, is it correct ? How do we do this using cosimplicial identities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of $s$ is good, perfectly fine.

How to do it with cosimplicial identities? Well, we have a canonical factorisation of any $f$ as $f=\delta\delta\delta\cdots\sigma\sigma\sigma$ where I've omitted whatever subscripts or superscripts are necessary. If $f$ is epi, that means there are no $\delta$ terms in this canonical factorisation. So $f$ is just the composite of some string of $\sigma_i$'s.

The cosimplicial identities give you an explicit way to find a right inverse to such a string. Well, the identities give you that canonical factorisation of $f$ (proof found in CWM, e.g.) and the easier cosimplicial identity: $\sigma_i\delta_i=\sigma_i\delta_{i+1}=\mathrm{Id}$ allows you to find a right inverse.

Comment: Why does $f$ being epic imply that there is no $\delta$ ? So here an inverse would be a product of $\delta$, and in fact with the cosimplcial identity you gave we would get two inverses.

Comment: Let's say $f=\delta g$ for some other $g$. Say, $f:[m]\to[n]$, $g:[m]\to[n-1]$, and the $\delta$ is $\delta_i$ for some $0\le i\le n$. Then the image of $f$ does not contain $i\in[n]$ by definition of $\delta_i$ @raisinsec so it fails to be epi

Comment: It is fine for there to be more than one section, more than one right inverse. For example $f:[3]\to[1]$ which sends $0,1\mapsto0,\,2,3,\mapsto1$ has: $0\mapsto 0,\,1\mapsto2$ and $0\mapsto1,\,1\mapsto2$ and $0\mapsto0,\,1\mapsto3$ and $0\mapsto1,\,1\mapsto3$ as all valid sections to $f$.